# Parsing Date JSON Crash in UK region

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am downloading json with a date string. An example is "2020-06-08T09:48:47.570"

I am easily able to convert this string into a date with a `DateFormatter` and a `dateFormat` of `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`. However, when I set the iPhone region to UK and the time display to 12 hours, the dateFormatter fails to parse the string.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter. You're provably missing `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` and `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the calendar of the formatter to an ISO8601 calendar

```
let dateString = "2020-06-08T09:48:47.570"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

or use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, however you have to append a `Z` time zone specifier

```
let dateString = "2020-06-08T09:48:47.570"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString + "Z")
```